# The events of the prophecies painting in Himalayas cave

Tags: lorien-legacies

Most of it is already clarified (which one in it and what happened/what does it mean) but i still did not understand some of it (guess i am missing something):

- A figure standing on a pine tree, throwing something down at three Mogadorians - which event and character does it apply to? Ella suggested it was Five but that all
- Setrákus Ra with a sword at his throat and dead Mogadorians surrounding him - does this depict the battle in Mexico near The Sanctuary?
- A planet cut in half, the top half in Earth with a ship approaching from the left and the bottom is dead and barren with a ship approaching it from the right - this is "explained" in the latest book by Number Four

  > My understanding is that the painter didn’t know who would win the war for Earth. That’s why they left it so vague

But this last one makes me wonder, all the previous ones are very accurate so why this sudden ambiguity?